# get value of input text on change

Tags: jquery, input, color-picker

I have this code with jquery colorpicker, onchange input #color show the input value in hex;
How could I do to get the color value on change?

```
<body>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="swatch" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
<input type="text" id="color">
```

script : refreshSwatch is a function witch get the slider color value, it works;

```
 function refreshSwatch(evt, ui) {
    var red = $("#red").slider("value"),
            green = $("#green").slider("option", "value"),
            blue = $("#blue").slider("value"),
            hex = hexFromRGB(red, green, blue);
    $("#swatch").css("background-color", "#" + hex);
    $("#color").val("#" + hex);
}
```

I want to get the color input value on change and then change the background color, but it doesn't work:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#color").change(function(){
        $("body").css("background-color", $("#color").val());
    });
})
```

http://jsbin.com/alefok/18/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See a working bin: http://jsbin.com/alefok/34/edit

Changed two things:

`$("#colour").val("#" + hex).change();` in this function: `function refreshSwatch(){}`

```
                       //--^^^^^^^^^-------triggered the change above here.
```

and here :

```
$("#colour").change(function(){
     $("body").css("background", $("#colour").val());
}).change(); //<-----trigger the change here
```

Answer (score 1):

In your link:

http://jsbin.com/alefok/18/edit

You have a typo in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="colour">
```

But you are using the selector `$("#color")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this it work for u

```
function refreshSwatch(evt, ui) {
    var red = $("#red").slider("value"),
            green = $("#green").slider("option", "value"),
            blue = $("#blue").slider("value"),
            hex = hexFromRGB(red, green, blue);
    $("#swatch").css("background-color", "#" + hex);
    $("#color").val("#" + hex);
    $("body").css("background-color", $("#colour").val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the scope of your callback, you can use `this` to reference the item in question. That is mostly a suggestion, your code worked just fine. The main issue in the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/alefok/18/edit) example you provided was that there were discrepancies between how the word "color" (or "colour") was spelled.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="color">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#color").change(function(){
        $("body").css("background-color", $(this).val());
    });
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/alefok/25/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this edit

```
function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
        var hex = [
            r.toString( 16 ),
            g.toString( 16 ),
            b.toString( 16 )
        ];
        $.each( hex, function( nr, val ) {
            if ( val.length === 1 ) {
                hex[ nr ] = "0" + val;
            }
        });
        return hex.join( "" ).toUpperCase();
    }
    function refreshSwatch(evt, ui) {

        var red = $( "#red" ).slider( "value" ),
                green = $( "#green" ).slider( "option", "value" ),
                blue = $( "#blue" ).slider( "value" ),
                hex = hexFromRGB( red, green, blue );

        $( "body" ).css( "background-color", "#" + hex );   //Here give body not div
        $("#colour").val("#" + hex);
    }
    $(function() {
        $( "#red, #green, #blue" ).slider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            max: 255,
            value: 127,
            slide: refreshSwatch,
            change: refreshSwatch
        });
        $( "#red" ).slider( "value", 255 );
        $( "#green" ).slider( "value", 140 );
        $( "#blue" ).slider( "value", 60 );
    });
});
```